# Sum of matrix with a $15\times15$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the $15\times 15$ matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&\cdots&15\\
16&17&18&19&\cdots&30\\
31&32&33&34&\cdots&45\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
211&212&213&214&\cdots&225
\end{pmatrix} $$

We are required to pick one number from each row and one number from each column.

If we add the numbers and get a sum $S$, and we do the same thing twice but with a different set, will the sum be the same?

Basically, if I do:

$$1+17+33+49+65+...+209+225$$

will it be the same if I picked different numbers such as:

$$16+32+48+64+....+208+224+15$$

I noticed from each number you add $16$. So for example, $$1+17+33+49+65+...+209+225$$

to go from term $1$ to term $2$, you add $16$ and so on.

I think it is the same but i'm not sure, can anyone see a counter-example?

Comment: "I noticed from each number you add 16." No idea what that means.

Comment: sorry, i'll be more specific. ok i updated.

Comment: Oh, you mean that these two sequences, specifically. There are a lot of such selections that don't have that property. For example, if you do the right-to-left diagonal, you get the same sum, as well.

Comment: oh you are right, that would be adding $14$ to each term.

Comment: And there are cases where there isn't a common sum.

Comment: Find a general way to express each element, then work out the sums or look for a counter example.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is the sum of these two matrices:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
15 & 15 & 15 &\dots & 15 \\
30 & 30 & 30 &\dots & 30 \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
210 & 210 & 210 & \dots & 210
\end{array}\right)
$$
and

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 15 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 15 \\1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 15 \\
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 15 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Can you see why each of these two matrices has the property you're asking about? Can you see why that property is preserved by addition?

Answer (score 1):

The entry in row $i$, column $j$ is $15i+j-15$. The way we pick the $15$ summands, each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ occurs exactly once and each $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ occurs exactly once. By rearranging the sumands we conclude that the sum is always
$$ 15\sum_{i=1}^{15}i+\sum_{j=1}^{15}j-15\cdot 15.$$